# Display Directions with React Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am new to React and am attempting to use google maps to display directions. I have been able to get it to display a single marker but have not found how to reconfigure the code to display the directions. Below is my most recent attempt but it will only display the map... any assistance is appreciated:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, DirectionsRenderer } from 'react-google-maps';
class Map extends Component {
   render() {
   const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 } }
        defaultZoom = { 13 }
      >

<DirectionsRenderer origin={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }} destination={{ lat: 41.756795, lng: -78.954298 }} />
      </GoogleMap>
   ));
   return(
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} /> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
        />
      </div>
   );
   }
};
export default Map;
```

I have the API key in a script tag in index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`DirectionsRenderer` component](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/components/DirectionsRenderer.md) does not accept `origin` and `destination` props, `directions` prop needs to be provided instead which value represents the response from `DirectionsService`, for example:

```
<DirectionsRenderer
      directions={this.state.directions}
 />
```

where

```
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

const origin = { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 };
const destination = { lat: 41.756795, lng: -78.954298 };

directionsService.route(
  {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  },
  (result, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      this.setState({
        directions: result
      });
    } else {
      console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
    }
  }
);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5cuf9v)

Comment: Thanks! This helped immensely

Comment: Remember, in Google Cloud Platform you'll need to enable "Directions API" to get it to work.  Google Cloud Platform > APIs & Services > Library > Search in the box for "Directions API" and then Enable.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the enough example for you to work with

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { withScriptjs } from "react-google-maps";




import  Map from './components/Map';

function App() {

  const MapLoader = withScriptjs(Map);

  return (

<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

  </header>
  <MapLoader
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And your Map.js file should look like this

```
/*global google*/
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    GoogleMap,
    DirectionsRenderer
} from "react-google-maps";
class Map extends Component {
    state = {
        directions: null,


};

componentDidMount() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    const origin = { lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 };
    const destination = { lat: 6.4667, lng:  3.4500};

    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            waypoints: [
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.4698,  3.5852)
                },
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.6018,3.3515)
                }
            ]
        },
        (result, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                console.log(result)
                this.setState({
                    directions: result
                });
            } else {
                console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
            }
        }
    );
}

render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 }}
            defaultZoom={13}
        >
            <DirectionsRenderer
                directions={this.state.directions}
            />
        </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMapExample
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />
        </div>


       );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: getting error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

Comment: how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @VadimGremyachev and @EmmanuelAdebayo's answers (many thanks!), but with an arrow function and a useState hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, Marker, DirectionsRenderer } from "react-google-maps";
/* global google */

const Map = ({ formattedOrigin, formattedDestination }) => {
  const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  let [directions, setDirections] = useState("");

  DirectionsService.route(
    {
      origin: formattedOrigin,
      destination: formattedDestination,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    },
    (result, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        setDirections(result);
      } else {
        console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
      }
    }
  );
  return (
    <section className="googleMap">
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={9} defaultCenter={{ lat: 41.75, lng: 1.8 }}>
        <Marker position={formattedOrigin} />
        <Marker position={formattedDestination} />
        {directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />}
      </GoogleMap>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

And then from your high order component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Home.css";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { googleMapsApiKey } from "../../data/constants";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import Map from "../presentational/Map";

const Home = () => {
  const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
  const formattedOrigin = useSelector(
    (state) => state.routeCalculatorReducer.loadCost?.originGeoCodedFormatted
  );
  const formattedDestination = useSelector(
    (state) =>
      state.routeCalculatorReducer.loadCost?.destinationGeoCodedFormatted
  );

  return (
    <main className="home">
      <section className="map">
        <WrappedMap
          googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${googleMapsApiKey}`}
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: "80vh" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          formattedOrigin={formattedOrigin}
          formattedDestination={formattedDestination}
        />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```